# Couldn’t find any executable in apache-maven-3.3.3

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a windows jenkins slave and I have download `apache-maven-3.3.3` on it.

It is located `C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3` This is copy and pasted from the windows explorer on my Windows slave.

Then when I point at this location in Jenkins and run a build. I get this error
`Couldn’t find any executable in C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3`

I have also tried `Couldn’t find any executable in C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin`

This works just fine on my linux slaves. What is the difference? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maven changed the name of the executable in Maven 3.3 from mvn.bat to mvn.cmd. Jenkins recognized mvn.cmd since Jenkins 1.613 (see this [commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/f7c0a49b4b40f5159545533fedf288ae2d11d693)). If you are on an earlier Jenkins version you can add a symlink from mvn.bat to mvn.cmd on windows as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The executable is in the `\bin` folder (namely, `mvn.bat`). Try to point Jenkins to `C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin`

Comment: `Couldn’t find any executable in C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin` It actually looks like it is called `mvn.cmd`.

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't work anymore? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28373

Answer (score 0):

#### First

Under your Windows machine
1. create an Environment Virable named `MAVEN_HOME` and set its value to `C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3`.
2. Add `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` into your System PATH

#### Second

Go to

> http://your-jenkins-server/computer/your-windows-slave/configure -->Node Properties-->Tool Locations-->(Maven)maven

and set its value to `C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\apache-maven-3.3.3` as well.

#### Third

Reconnect your jenkins slave, then rerun your job.

Comment: So I completed these steps. However, I did not disconnect my server when I added the new node property. Is this needed for the settings to sync?

Comment: Based on my experience，you'd better disconnect and reconnect the node for the settings to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Well for me it was wrong setting for maven. Go to configure, under post build action, go to advanced setting and there fix the Maven version to be used, i changed it to maven 3.3.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows. The accepted answers does not work for me. So, I have to create a new Maven in Jenkins and select the option "Install automatically". Then it works.